# App communicate with message queue directly vs. communicating with a proxy (front end service)

Tags: architecture, message-queue, iot, proxy-server

We are working a new architecture for our product. Out product is not exactly IoT - devices communicate with a single box at the client site and that box communicates with our servers.

We have 2 options:

1. The box will send a message directly to a queue which will be picked up by the worker server and handled at it's turn.
2. The box will send a message to a front end server. All that server does is put the message in the queue for the worker to handle.

There are pros and cons to each method. Number one pro for communicating directly with the queue is that we don't need to spend money on machines to hold the front end services.

The biggest pro for using a front end server is that it acts as an abstraction layer against the queue technology we are working with - so if we change the queue we don't need to update all clients with a new version for them to keep working. Another advantage that we think about is the it allows us to simulate synchronios  calls.

Of course, there are many pros and cons to each. What is the suggested way to work? best practices? security?

Comment: What's the messaging protocol do you plan on using? Is it mqtt? Is bi-directional communication with devices required?

Comment: @SergeiRodionov Most chances it will be AMQP. Some the services will require  bi-directional communication.

Comment: I don't have much experience with AMQP in this context. We use mosquitto/mqtt for bi-directional communication with end-points. Perhaps you could chain two mqtt servers to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

One aspect to consider is scalability. You need to support load balancers for that.

While some message queue protocols can run over load balancers (see e.g. [Load blancing MQTT broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360172/load-blancing-mqtt-broker/31372389#31372389)), I advise to test that before making a decision.
If you use a plain REST, then load balancer compatibility is a non-issue.

Other areas to check are:
* Firewall compatibility: is the "box" in a different netowkr (e.g. company intranet) than the server? Also in that case HTTP/REST is a more safer choice.